# Changing :before and :after content on ::selection

Tags: css, opera, pseudo-element

I'm wondering if it's possible to change the text of an element on selection. For example, if I had

```
<span class=time>12:00</span>
```

Would it be possible to change the content to `[12:00]` by using CSS `:before`, `:after`, and `::selection` pseudo-elements?

```
.time::selection:before {
    content: '[';
}
.time::selection:after {
    content: ']';
}
```

Although my current project requires a CSS solution (and also only needs to work in Opera), I'd not be averse to JavaScript solutions if CSS seems impossible, just for future reference.

In case it is of any use, I'm attempting to change the formatting of Opera's IRC setup using `im.css` in order to make copy/pasted logs format more like they do from conventional IRC clients.

Comment: What happens if I highlight `12:0` only? Would it render as `[12:0]0`?

Comment: You raise a good point that I'd not considered. For my current purposes, it doesn't really matter, but I'm sure that's exactly the sort of thing that might end up making it impossible to do with CSS :P

Answer (score 1):

You cannot currently nest the `::before` or `::after` pseudo-elements with any other pseudo-elements (not even themselves).

Comment: There are also complications like partial selections as I mention in my earlier comment, nesting selection rules in descendants, and overall impact on performance, that forced the CSS working group to drop `::selection` out of CSS3 UI altogether.